# Problems with device target for iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

)
Hello all :-)

I want to release an iPhone/iPod Touch only app. However, I know iPad users can still download the app from the app store, which is fine by me. I was simulating my app on simulator to see how it would look like on an iPad. When I simulated it, the app looked terrible: the layout was not the same as the iPhone version, some labels were colliding and buttons were "cut" out of the screen.

I want iPad users to have the same view as an iPhone. I believe a 1x/2x button would appear on the screen in that case. How can I do that?

Any help/advice would be really appreciated!
Thank you :-)

Comment: use generic size classes . that will help you to have same layout in every device .

Comment: Disable app for iPad from your targets like @matt suggested in his answer. Then all that you manage for iPhone 4s will be managed for iPad as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you upload your app to the App Store it will also allow iPad users to download the iPhone version of the app. This will have the 1x/2x button you are looking for.

However if you test your project on the iPad simulator before you upload the app, it will not be the same iPhone version of the app that the iPad users will see. Instead the simulator will run an actual iPad version of the app which is not what your looking for.

In your project settings, set your target device to iPhone only. Upload the app. When iPad users download the app they will get the iPhone only version with the 1x/2x button for the iPad.

Comment: Thanks! This is the exact thing I was looking for. I don't have to change anything since my Deployment Target is already set to iPhone. I was afraid the simulator version is the exact same one that iPad users will see.

Comment: "However if you test your project on the iPad simulator before you upload the app, it will not be the same iPhone version of the app that the iPad users will see." That is not true. If the OP sees an iPad native app on the simulator, he will be uploading an iPad native app to the store. "I was afraid the simulator version is the exact same one that iPad users will see." And you are right to be afraid of that.

Answer (score 0):

In your project settings, make sure the "Devices" settings is "Universal" (this is under "Deployment Info"). If it was not before, you may have to make some layout adjustments.

Comment: I want the app to be for iPhone only. If an iPad user downloads it, I still want it to look like an iPhone screen. My deployment target is iPhone

Answer (score 0):

Use Autolayout for fixing the design issues

in storyboard right pane -> attribute inspector -> simulated metrics-> select inferred in size for all controllers

Answer (score 0):

You should be seeing this in the simulator (note the letterboxing on all sides):

[image]

And your build settings should show `1` as the target device family:

[image]

If not, you are iPad-native and that's the source of the trouble.